# SSH connection asks for password although key is accepted

Tags: ssh, rsa

I'm getting prompted for a password even though it looks like my SSH key is accepted. As far as I can tell, the line "Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277" in the logs below mean my key is accepted.

Here are debug logs:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/sam/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp <<HASH REDACTED>>
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sam/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sam/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
```

Help much appreciated, everyone I've found who is having SSH problems fails at an earlier point that I'm seeing.

Answer (score 16):

Your private key was most certainly *not* accepted, it was only attempted. There are a number of ways SSH key based authentication can fail, and the logging is not really that great so debugging this particular problem is one of my personal pet peeves. I've found that the error is **usually** a result of one of the following situations.

- **Your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file is too open.** For your own protection `sshd` attempts to protect you from yourself. If the permissions on your authorized keys file then it will fail the authentication. Run `chmod -R go-rwx ~/.ssh`.
- **Your public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is malformed.** This could be a result of any number of problems, but the most common is a copy paste issue. Some terminals, when copy/pasting across screens, will interpret a line wrap as a new line. Each entry in the `authorized_keys` file **must** be a single line. You can check this by changing the size of your terminal emulator and seeing if there's a break, comparing the output of `wc -l ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` against the number of keys that *should* be in there, or whatever works best for you. Just make sure each key is one line and you should be fine.

Comment: For anyone coming here trying to understand where the 'access is too open' issue originates, I'm posting here because it took me quite a bit of searches to find it myself. This is enforced by the [`StrictModes`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#StrictModes) setting in `sshd_config`.  It's not recommended to disable, but it is helpful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 8):

The ssh -v output you pasted suggested that it tried to use the key but that didn't work, so it moved on to keyboard-interactive.

Have you checked the authentication log on the server you are connecting to? (eg, /var/log/auth.log).  If your setup at the remote end is incorrect, eg wrong permissions, then ssh -v (or -vv or -vvv) won't tell you this, but it will be logged by sshd.

Comment: /var/log/auth.log held the answer for me: "Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /root"

Comment: For anyone coming here trying to understand where the `'bad ownership or modes for directory'` error comes from, I'm posting here because it took me quite a bit of searches to find it myself. This is enforced by the [`StrictModes`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#StrictModes) setting in `sshd_config`.  It's not recommended to disable, but it is helpful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, file `/var/log/authlog` showed:

```
[ID 800047 auth.info] Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory
```

I had checked correct ownership/permissions in `.ssh` but the `$HOME` had 777 permissions.
Setting 755 permissions on `$HOME` allowed sftp to work. Thanks again.

Comment: For anyone coming here trying to understand where the `'bad ownership or modes for directory'` error comes from, I'm posting here because it took me quite a bit of searches to find it myself. This is enforced by the [`StrictModes`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#StrictModes) setting in `sshd_config`.  It's not recommended to disable, but it is helpful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the server (directly or via another login), check the server logs in (say) `/var/log/sshd` or `/var/log/secure` depending on your system

It is typically caused by a permissions error on your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Make sure it's not world readable, but crucially that it is readable by the user (sometimes a service user) running sshd

Comment: Which system uses `/var/log/sshd`? Systems I know use either `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure`.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in remote is important (`600` for my systems RHEL and Solaris)

Permissions of you home directory in remote is important (`700` in my systems)

At the end run `sshd` in remote machine in debug mode on another port can be helpful:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -p 5555 -dd
```

`5555` is an example port, you can change it. For more info in this regard you can see: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2219973.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/sbin/restorecon -r /root/.ssh
```

A possible problem with setting permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is a problem if I use the `sshd` service. To avoid this problem, stop the `sshd` service with `service sshd stop` and then start the `sshd` daemon from the command prompt with `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd`.